# Show the complete description of an example

Tags: ruby, rspec

In RSpec, how can we generate a string from an example, representing the current meta description of the current example?

Example:

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::Public::Signin::ByEmailController, type: :controller do
  describe 'POST #create' do
    context 'when the provider is "email"' do
      context 'when there is a saved email' do
        context 'when the password is good' do
          it 'signs in' do
            expect(current_metadata_description).to eq 'Api::V1::Public::Signin::ByEmailController POST #create when the provider is "email" when there is a saved email when the password is good signs in'
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As we can see, the current meta description of the given example is:

> Api::V1::Public::Signin::ByEmailController POST #create when the provider is "email" when there is a saved email when the password is good signs in

Thanks.

**Edit:**

The `current_metadata_description` is not provided by RSpec. I just invented it to give an example of what I would like to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am unsure what your overall intentions are for doing this.

`Rspec::Core::ExampleGroup.it` yields a `RSpec::Core::Example` to the block. As with all yielding methods one can capture the yielded `Object` in a block local variable. `RSpec::Core::Example` has a `full_description` method which appears to be what you are looking for. [RSpec Source](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/example.rb#L17).

For Example (no pun intended):

```
describe String do 
  context 'Down' do 
    context 'Deeper' do 
      it 'can describe itself' do |ex|
        # ex is the specific RSpec::Core::Example for this it block
        expect(ex.full_description).to eq('String Down Deeper can describe itself')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

running this will return

```
.
Finished in 0.003 seconds (files took 0.21998 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

It is imperative that you capture the yielded value if you want the desired output as the block itself is executed in the context of an instance of `RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup` so calling `self.class.metadata[:full_description]` will contain the description of the `RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup` but not the `RSpec::Core::Example` itself (e.g. "String Down Deeper")

As described in the docs if this is for logging purposes (or something similar where you would like this information for each example) you can access the `RSpec::Core::Example` in `Hooks` excerpt:

```
# Useful for configuring logging and/or taking some action based
# on the state of an example's metadata.
#
#     RSpec.configure do |config|
#       config.before do |example|
#         log example.description
#       end
#
#       config.after do |example|
#         log example.description
#       end
#
#       config.around do |example|
#         log example.description
#         example.run
#       end
#     end
```

If you really wanted to patch this in (and I am not endorsing it) You could do the following

```
class RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup 
  def instance_exec(*args,&blk)
    if args.first.is_a?(RSpec::Core::Example)
      self.define_singleton_method(:current_metadata_description) do
        args.first.full_description
      end
    end
    super(*args,&blk)
  end
end
```

Then your test would be exactly as you stated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run rspec with [`--format` option](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-6/docs/command-line/format-option):

```
bundle exec rspec --format documentation
```

**Update**:

I don't know any rspec method that would do that for you. One way I can think of is, write the spec description to a file while running the tests and then read the description from it in your custom `current_metadata_description` method. Here is a tutorial on [Generating documentation from specs.](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/21/generating-documentation-from-specs/) Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I'd like to have a method such as `current_metadata_description` in order to fetch the current metadata description from inside an example.

Comment: The link looks like it provides ideas on doing what you're asking.